# How to show administration permission

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I show the access control before creating a new file/folder in `C#` to obtain the system administration permission?
I need this because I'm creating a file/folder or directory in a folder that needs the admin's permission and I want to avoid opening program as administrator every time.

I need something like the following code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(fileName, new DirectorySecurity(fileName2, AccessControlSections.Owner));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? [File.SetAccessControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

It allows you to set permissions on a specified file.

Comment: There are also the attributes [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, Name = "FullTrust")]
to be added directly above the method making the security-enabled call.